# iOS 5 not in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I purchased Xcode when it was still $5 in the mac app store (and before iOS 5 came out). When iOS 5 came out, I updated it, and the update details stated that it had support for the iOS 5 SDK. However, when I go into my Build Settings, iOS 4.3.3 is the latest SDK version listed. How can I get the iOS 5 SDK? If it helps or matters, I'm developing on a late 2006 Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the stupid things about getting XCode in the mac apps store is it downloads an installer and puts it in your applications directory. Check in there, you may need to run it manually.

Comment: Ohhhhh.. I remember having to do that when I first installed it, but I didn't think I had to when I updated. I was wondering why I still have Install Xcode in my Applications folder. I'm updating it now and I'll post back if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the iOS simulator didn't download, hit Cmd+, to open preferences and go to the 'downloads' tab.

Also available are debugging tools for older iOS SDK's and some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's Developer website](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/):

> iOS 5 beta and iOS 5 SDK are available to iOS Developer Program
>   members.

Looks like you'll have to pay to join the developer program for $99.

Comment: Really? That's pretty stupid. When will it become "free" like the previous versions? Also, isn't that kind of limiting app development? For me, I haven't made an app I want to submit to the app store yet so I'm refusing to pay Apple until I have to. That really sucks in that case because you'll spend all that time developing for an old SDK and then having to possibly update parts of your code after you pay.

Comment: To any future searchers, the latest SDK actually was available, I just forgot to run the updater. Thanks for everyone's help.